# MATLAB Error: Can't check VCRTs

Tags: matlab

When I start MATLAB I suddenly receive the following error message on the command line:

> ERROR: Can't check 8.0 VCRTs (starter line:956) System Error:
>   0x00000005 ERROR: Can't check 9.0 VCRTs (starter line:995) System
>   Error: 0x00000005 Installing required 8.0 run-time libraries. This may
>   take a few minutes...

I tried to repair and reinstall the Visual C++ Redistributables (2005 and 2008), but that didn't solve the problem. Doing online research I mainly found out that people who had a similar problem reinstalled windows. Well, does anyone have another idea what I could try in order to solve that?

Comment: Steve Lord, MathWorks employee, states [in this answer](http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/296819) that you should [contact MathWorks support](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-CEECTU/?solution=1-CEECTU) You're paying for it anyway. Support is also [saying you should contact Microsoft/your IT department](http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92611-why-does-matlab-crash-upon-start-with-error-code-0xc0150004-or-give-a-system-error-14001-stating-tha). I'm surprised a full OS reinstall seems the only way to solve this problem.

Comment: @Adriaan the beauty of "support" is to push the problem to someone else, hence they can say that they solved the problem in less than a minute, with a beautiful average response time and response rate. Just business as usual.